# Firebase deleted data still there

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i have a behavior that I can't understand.
I delete a node on `firebase database` and I still receive the data during observing .value. But in firebase database the node is deleted.

I have a node called `users_shoppinglists`. Here are all id's of the users nodes to observe stored. Then I iterate all the id's to observe and call a function that observes each ID.

When I need to delete a list I update a node called `status` on the `shoppinglists` node and delete all to this list related data via cloud functions.

But the data is still received during observe. It seems I receive the data again before it is completely deleted.

Iterate all id's:

```
func ObserveAllList() -> Void{

    if currentUser == nil { return }

    self.ShowActivityIndicator()
    ref.child("users_shoppinglists").child(currentUser!.id!).observe(.value, with: { (usersListsSnap) in

        if usersListsSnap.value is NSNull { self.HideActivityIndicator(); return }

        for listSnap in usersListsSnap.children {

            let list = listSnap as! DataSnapshot

            self.ObserveSingleList(listID: list.key)

        }

    }) { (error) in

        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
        let title = String.OnlineFetchRequestError
        let message = error.localizedDescription
        self.ShowAlertMessage(title: title, message: message)
        return

    }


}
```

Call function to observe each ID:

```
func ObserveSingleList(listID:String) -> Void {

    self.ShowActivityIndicator()
    ref.child("shoppinglists").child(listID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.value is NSNull { self.HideActivityIndicator(); return }


        //Read listData
        var newList = ShoppingList()
        newList.id = snapshot.key
        newList.name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "listName").value as? String
        newList.owneruid = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "owneruid").value as? String
        newList.relatedStore = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "relatedStore").value as? String

        //Read List items
        self.ref.child("listItems").child(listID).observe(.value, with: { (itemSnap) in

            var newItems = [ShoppingListItem]()
            for items in itemSnap.children {

                let item = items as! DataSnapshot
                var newItem = ShoppingListItem()
                newItem.id = item.key
                newItem.listID  = listID
                newItem.isSelected = item.childSnapshot(forPath: "isSelected").value as? Bool
                newItem.itemName = item.childSnapshot(forPath: "itemName").value as? String
                newItem.sortNumber = item.childSnapshot(forPath: "sortNumber").value as? Int
                newItems.append(newItem)

            }
            newList.items = newItems

            //Read List members
            self.ref.child("shoppinglist_member").child(listID).observe(.value, with: { (memberSnap) in

                var newMembers = [ShoppingListMember]()
                for members in memberSnap.children {

                    let member = members as! DataSnapshot
                    var m = ShoppingListMember()
                    m.memberID = member.key
                    m.status = member.value as? String
                    newMembers.append(m)

                }
                newList.members = newMembers

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if let index = allShoppingLists.index(where: { $0.id == listID }){

                        allShoppingLists[index] = newList

                    } else {

                        allShoppingLists.append(newList)

                    }

                    self.HideActivityIndicator()
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.ShoppingBuddyListDataReceived, object: nil, userInfo: nil)

                }


            }, withCancel: { (error) in

                self.HideActivityIndicator()
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
                let title = String.OnlineFetchRequestError
                let message = error.localizedDescription
                self.ShowAlertMessage(title: title, message: message)
                return

            })

        }, withCancel: { (error) in

            self.HideActivityIndicator()
            NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
            let title = String.OnlineFetchRequestError
            let message = error.localizedDescription
            self.ShowAlertMessage(title: title, message: message)
            return

        })


    }) { (error) in

        self.HideActivityIndicator()
        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
        let title = String.OnlineFetchRequestError
        let message = error.localizedDescription
        self.ShowAlertMessage(title: title, message: message)
        return

    }
}
```

Cloud function:

```
    //****************************************************************************************************************/
// Handles an action when status value changed in users_shoppinglists node
//****************************************************************************************************************/
exports.handle_ListStatusUpdate = functions.database.ref('/shoppinglists/{listID}').onUpdate(event => {

    var listData = event.data.val()
    console.log('Status', listData.status)

    //handle deleted by owner
    if (String(listData.status) == 'deleted by owner') {

        //Get all members to delete the list on their users_shoppinglists node
        return admin.database().ref('shoppinglist_member').child(event.params.listID).once('value').then(listMember => {

            var promises = []
            listMember.forEach(function (member) {

                promises.push(admin.database().ref('users_shoppinglists').child(member.key).child(event.params.listID).set(null).then(() => {

                    return admin.database().ref('shoppinglist_member').child(event.params.listID).set(null).then(() => {

                        // delete the original shopping list
                        return admin.database().ref('shoppinglists').child(event.params.listID).set(null).then(() => {

                            return admin.database().ref('listItems').child(event.params.listID).set(null).then(() => {

                            })

                        })

                    })

                }))

            })

        })

    }

});/*********************************************************************************************************** */
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue on Simulator. It was not only .value but .childRemoved and .childChanged were not triggered at all (only .childAdded was working).

Tried on iPhone and it worked. Then I made "Erase All Content And Settings..." to Simulator and it started to work again on Simulator too.

My bet is that firebase cache gets dirty during development, while you add or remove observers in code and probably change structure in database and at some point it just stops reacting appropriately.